# CSS Flexbox container does not vertically scroll on iOS devices

Tags: html, css

There are several posts about iOS mobile scrolling issues. None seem to address what I am experiencing specifically.

I have an Angular Material application that uses a lot of mat-table components. I wrap these tables in a flexbox to fill the height of the screen no matter how much height the table content is taking up.

When trying to scroll these tables vertically on mobile iOS devices, nothing happens. The content just disappears under my footer.

```
 <table mat-table [ngClass]="{'blurred':loading}" [dataSource]="dataSource">//Lots of content.</table>
```

That's all this table is. Simple enough.

I have tried this and a bunch of other things from the different posts:

```
table {
   overflow-x: auto !important;
   overflow: auto !important;
}

table {
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}

table {
   -webkit-overflow-scrolling: auto;
}
```

Now, I have seen posts saying that a height may need to be defined. But I don't want to define a height, that is why I am using flexbox. I have a header, a body (a sidenav containing the table) and a footer. The body fills the remaining space, so the layout is consistent crossed all screen sizes.

This works perfectly fine on windows and android. Is there any solution for this on iOS?

**EDIT:**

I cannot show the UI of the actual app, so here is the structure from a test app. This would not scroll on iOS even though there is a vertical scrollbar.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Without a fixed height, when would it ever overflow? Overflow implies the content has gone past the bounds of the container.

Comment: @BugsArePeopleToo Edited post to include screenshots.

Answer (score 1):

You should try using a support query to target iOS devices and add the flexbox styling accordingly:

`@supports (-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch) {
    display: flex;
    align-content: stretch;
}`

Comment: That is a cool approach, but it does not work unfortunately. Same issue. Even if I set the flexbox to align-content: stretch; by default it does not work.

Comment: Have you tried using a media query to adjust the sizing for iOS screen?

Comment: Have you looked into virtual scrolling which comes with the angular material cdk? Maybe you are already using but I know this new feature is packed into Angular 7+

Answer (score 0):

You can define the height with 100vh. This will cause the overflow you need.

Comment: I don't want a height on the table. That is why I am using Flexbox. This table is part of a dynamic angular component that gets used in many different situations. Adding a height breaks containers such as dialogs for example. The table, the right side nav and the bottom toolbar are all part of the same component.